# SQL PnL Inventory Query

Tags: sql, inventory-management

I have a table containing a list of trades:

```
Security ;   Quantity ; Price ;  Consid
 1. IBM  ;    +1,000 ;   20  ;  -20k
 2. IBM  ;    +2,000 ;   22  ;  -44k
 3. IBM  ;    -1,000 ;   30  ;  +30k
 4. IBM  ;    -2,000 ;   20  ;  +40k
 5. IBM  ;    -2,000 ;   20  ;  -20k
```

So the PnL is basically the sum of the Consid column so before Trade#5 was added the PnL would be +6k.

After Trade #5 was added this shows the PnL as -14k which isnt really that reflective of where we stand.

What I would like is some way of filtering out the not closed trades? So Trade#5 will only be allowed into the sum when we have added a purchase of 2k IBM shares to the table.

My intial attempt at this was:

```
set @Ret = @Ret + isnull((SELECT SUM(GC) AS GS
FROM  (SELECT SUM(GrossConsid) * - 1 AS GC
                     FROM   Trades AS CT
                     WHERE  (SpecialCond = 'Prop') AND (SettType <> 'Futures') AND (TrdDt <= @Date) AND (TrdDt >=@StartDate) AND (Name = 'my_Comp')
                     GROUP BY ABS(Quantity)
                     HAVING (SUM(Quantity) = 0)) AS dt),0)
```

but I have no figured out that there is an edge condition where by if I have a trades with a Quantity of +5,+5,-5 it doesnt get counted because the `(SUM(Quantity) = 0))`  evaluates to false.

Any ideas on how I can rectify this?

Thanks Chris

Comment: If the buy side is your positive Quantity trades and the Sell side is the negative Quantity trades, how can you tell then position 5 is not close but position 4 is?  Do you have another column or indicator that position 4 belongs to the trade in position 2? Is it simply the order in which the trades are listed in the table for example, so position 5 is the last one and so must be the open position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Runnable Example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/97892/)

```
DECLARE @tbl AS TABLE (Seq int, Security varchar(3), Quantity int, Price int, Consid int) ;
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
(1, 'IBM', 1000, 20, -20000)
,(2, 'IBM', 2000, 22, -44000)
,(3, 'IBM', -1000, 30, 30000)
,(4, 'IBM', -2000, 20, 40000)
,(5, 'IBM', -2000, 20, -20000);

WITH RunningInventory AS (
SELECT l.Seq, SUM(r.Quantity) AS Inv
FROM @tbl AS l
LEFT JOIN @tbl r
ON r.Seq <= l.Seq
GROUP BY l.Seq
)
SELECT *
FROM @tbl AS trx
INNER JOIN RunningInventory
    ON trx.Seq = RunningInventory.Seq
WHERE RunningInventory.Inv >= 0 ;
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responsess

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responsess, first of all to explain my problem a bit clearer: I can have a negative or a postive or zero total quantity at any time. Whilst I could have a flag detailing open or closed positions that wouldnt be very scalable or as automated as I would like. @NathanDeWitt. I think that @CadeRoux's idea could work, I'll need to play with the numbers first, my intitial thoughts were that assumes that I am inputting trades chronologically, which will be true most of the time but there wil be edge cases when that fails but I think that could work

Comment: My other thought was to use a weighted average price to work out the PnL, If I go that route I'll post the code

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using SQL to match up your inventory, can you have your app set a flag in an additional "Closed" column?  Then you could do this:

```
SELECT Security, SUM(Consid)
FROM mytable
WHERE Closed = 1
GROUP BY Security
```

Answer (score 0):

Cant say about your logic, just fixing what you say is wrong:

```
HAVING (case when SUM(Quantity) = 0 then 1 else 0 end)
```